# TIMER Logic used in PIC15F1516 microcontroller

Tags: c, timer, embedded, microcontroller, pic

I am using PIC15F1516 microcontroller, and doing reverse engineering to understand the code without any documentation.  I failed to understand use of timer and logic implemented in main.c

- Timer0RegValue = 64536.0
- Prescalar = 1
- Delay =  ( (65536-Timer0RegValue)*(Prescalar*4) ) / Fosc = 0.001 Sec

I can understand in the main function timer is updated with value of 1mSec, however, I could not get after how much time ProcessTenthSec() and ProcessTwelfthSec() will get executed?

```
    void TMR1_Initialize(void)
    {
    //Set the Timer to the options selected in the GUI

    //T1CKPS 1:1; T1OSCEN disabled; nT1SYNC synchronize; TMR1CS FOSC/4; TMR1ON disabled; 
    T1CON = 0x00;

    //T1GSS T1G; TMR1GE disabled; T1GTM disabled; T1GPOL low; T1GGO_nDONE done; T1GSPM disabled; 
    T1GCON = 0x00;

    //TMR1H 252; 
    TMR1H = 0xFC;

    //TMR1L 24; 
    TMR1L = 0x18;

    // Load the TMR value to reload variable
   // 6396= 0xFC18
   // Delay =  ( (65536-Timer0RegValue)*(Prescalar*4) ) / Fosc;
   // Delay =  ( (65536-6396)*(1*4) ) / 500000;
   // Delay = 

    timer1ReloadVal=(TMR1H << 8) | TMR1L;

    // Clearing IF flag before enabling the interrupt.
    PIR1bits.TMR1IF = 0;

    // Enabling TMR1 interrupt.
    //PIE1bits.TMR1IE = 1;

    // Set Default Interrupt Handler
    //TMR1_SetInterruptHandler(TMR1_DefaultInterruptHandler);

    // Start TMR1
    //TMR1_StartTimer();
}

#define TENTH_SEC_RELOAD     156
#define TWELFTH_SEC_RELOAD   130
void main(void)
{
    // initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    // When using interrupts, you need to set the Global and Peripheral Interrupt Enable bits
    // Use the following macros to:
    // Enable the Global Interrupts
    INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptEnable();
    // Enable the Peripheral Interrupts
    INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptEnable();
   byTenthSec = TENTH_SEC_RELOAD
  byTwelfthSec = TWELFTH_SEC_RELOAD   

    while (1)
    {

        if(PIR1bits.TMR1IF)
        {
            T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 0;
            //TMR1H 252; 
            TMR1H = 0xFC;
            //TMR1L 24; 
            TMR1L = 0x18;
            T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 1;
            PIR1bits.TMR1IF = 0;

            if(--byTenthSec == 0)
            {
                byTenthSec = TENTH_SEC_RELOAD;
                ProcessTenthSec();
            }
            if(--byTwelfthSec == 0)
            {
                if(byTwelfthFix--)
                {
                    byTwelfthSec = TWELFTH_SEC_RELOAD   ;
                }
                else
                {
                    byTwelfthFix = 3;
                    byTwelfthSec = TWELFTH_SEC_RELOAD  + 1;
                }
                ProcessTwelfthSec();
            }
        }
        //if an ADC conversion is in progress do a low priority task 
        if(uHiPriTasks.HighPriority)
        {
            if(uHiPriTasks.One)
                Function1();
            else if(uHiPriTasks.Two)
                Function2();
            else if(uHiPriTasks.Three)
                Function3();
            else if(uHiPriTasks.four)
                Function4();
            else if(uHiPriTasks.five)
                Function4();
        }
        if(uWatchdog.byWatchdog == WDT_ALL_TASKS_COMPLETE)
        {
            //reset the watchdog task structure
            uWatchdog.byWatchdog = 0;
            //restart the watchdog timer
            CLRWDT();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What, specifically, are you confused about?

Comment: It seems that `Fosc` is *not* 4 MHz, because `TENTH_SEC_RELOAD` is not 100.

Comment: `TMR1H << 8` is a bug since PIC has 16 bit `int`. Also replace the magic numbers for register setups with meaningful preprocessor constants. You should have something like `TMR1H = THIS | THAT;`. A comment saying that 0xFC hex is 252 dec is completely meaningless. Nobody cares about what decimal representation a hardware register got.